# Simple regex to match word in the format variable = [[ word ]] in php

Tags: php, regex

I have to search a lot of text with format example

```
traded_as = {{NASDAQ|GOOG}}<br>{{NASDAQ|GOOGL}}<br>[[Company name]]<br>.
```

the general format of the text is `variable = some text here [[ word ]] some text here`.
 can someone help me with general   regex expression that can get me only the word in side [[ word  ]] regardless of the nature of the text that comes before or after it.
 I tried to create different Regx expression with the help of online regex testers but it gives me wrong match when the nature  of text that comes before it or after it change.

this one of the reqex expression that I tried

```
$re1='.*?'; # Non-greedy match on filler
  $re2='((?:[a-z][a-z]+))'; # Word 1
  $re3='(\\s+)';    # White Space 1
  $re4='(=)';   # Any Single Character 1
  $re5='(\\s+)';    # White Space 2
  $re6='.*?';   # Non-greedy match on filler
  $re7='((?:[a-z][a-z]+))'; # Word 2

  if ($c=preg_match_all ("/".$re1.$re2.$re3.$re4.$re5.$re6.$re7."/is", $txt, $matches))
  {
      $word1=$matches[1][0];
      $ws1=$matches[2][0];
      $c1=$matches[3][0];
      $ws2=$matches[4][0];
      $word2=$matches[5][0];
      print "($word1) ($ws1) ($c1) ($ws2) ($word2) \n";
  }
```

Comment: You should also add the regex that you have already tried.

Comment: You can try regex first at sites like http://regex101.com and similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
preg_match('/\[\[([^]]*)\]]/', $txt, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $string = "{{NASDAQ|GOOG}}<br>{{NASDAQ|GOOGL}}<br>[[Company name]]<br>";
    preg_match('/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/', $string, $regs);
        $result = $regs[1];
        echo $result;
        //Company name
?>
```

http://ideone.com/yH6eD9

```
Match the character “[” literally «\[»
Match the character “[” literally «\[»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character “]” literally «\]»
Match the character “]” literally «\]»
```